# How to install wammu in ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy)

Tags: apt, ppa

I've tried following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wammu
```

I get following message in terminal :

```
lekhnath@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install wammu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wammu is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'wammu' has no installation candidate
```

I've also tried to install it through 'Ubuntu Software Center' but installation is never success.

I've also tried adding `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/ppa/ubuntu trusty main` (got this link from here ->  https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) directly in 'Software & Updates' system settings and tried to install again:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wammu
```

But still getting the same message as above. **What should I do to install wammu in Ubuntu 13.10 ?**

Comment: Hi Lekhnath, was my answer of help to you? Please indicate also if things worked out, so it can help other with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

This PPA doesn't have packages for saucy/13.10. Only for 12.04, 14.04, 14.10 and 15.04. I would suggest you update to 14.04, which is an LTS release, and a direct increment to the 13.10 you have.